# problema com inversão de valores de um vetor

Tags: c, c++

Boa noite, não consigo achar problema em um código meu, é um exercício do site codewars(https://www.codewars.com/kata/sorting-on-planet-twisted-3-7), pra quem não conhece o site,é um site para treinar programação, aqui estou apenas tratando da inversão do 3 e do 7, **ex: entra um `array{ 1,3,4,7,13,17}` o array deveria sair `{1,7,4,3,17,13}`, o meu problema é que não consigo fazer o 3 sair como 7, o resultado dessa função a seguir é `{1,3,4,7,17,13}`, o meu único problema é o numero 3. Não sei se minha logica está errada, ou algum outro erro.** *Por isso peço a ajuda de vocês*

```
int* sortTwisted37(int* array, int arrayLength){

    bool v;


    for(int i=0;i<=arrayLength;i++){

       if(array[i]<=10){

           if(array[i]==7){
                array[i]=array[i]-4;
                v=true;
           }else if(array[i]==3){
               array[i]=array[i]+4;
               v==true;
           }
       }else 
           v=false;

           if(((array[i]-7)%10==0)&v==false){

               array[i]=array[i]-4;
           }else if(((array[i]-3)%10==0)&v==false){

               array[i]=array[i]+4;
           }

       cout << array[i] << endl;

    }
}
```

Desculpe se algo estiver errado, sou novo no site

Comment: Talvez seja interessante você [edit] a pergunta e descrever o que a função deveria fazer. Você apenas disse que o 3 seria o 7 e vice-versa, mas não disse o que é preciso fazer com esta informação.

Comment: Uma dica e colocar o seu problema no titulo da pergunta, e bom também colocar qual comportamento que seu código deveria ter e o que você já tentou para resolver. Assim facilita para quem for te ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Seria isso?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int posicao(int *v, int tam, int num) {

    int pos, i=0;
    for(; i < tam; i++) {
        if(v[i] == num) {
            pos = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return pos;
}

void trocar(int *v, int tam, int n1, int n2) {

    int pos1 = posicao(v, tam, n1);
    int pos2 = posicao(v, tam, n2);

    int *p1 = &v[pos1];
    int *p2 = &v[pos2];

    int tmp = *p1;
    *p1 = *p2;
    *p2 = tmp;
}

int main()
{

    int vet[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int tam = sizeof(vet) / sizeof(int);
    trocar(vet, tam, 1, 4);

    for(int i=0; i<tam; i++) {
       printf("%3d", vet[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Não conheço a sintaxe de c++ então vou fazer em c porque a lógica é a mesma.
Pelo que eu entendi da questão, é um planeta onde a ordem de 3 e 7 e invertida. Logo toda vez que eu encontrar 3 eu troco por 7 e vice-versa.

```
void twist3_7(int *valores, int tamanho){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < tam; i++){
        if(*(valores + i) % 10 == 3)
             *(valores + i) += 4;
        if(*(valores + i) % 10 == 7)
             *(valores + i) -= 4;
    }
}
```

Essa função faz a troca necessária.

Comment: Acredito que a lógica aplicada só funcione quando os valores estão no algarismo das unidades. Se for nas dezenas, por exemplo 30 ou 37, sairia 30 e 33 respectivamente.

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma genérica e elegante de solucionar esse problema é converter os números para strings e analisá-los dígito a dígito. Dessa forma, sua solução fica independente da quantidade de dígitos máxima possível.

Abaixo seguem as implementações de duas funções: `troca` e `opera`.

- A função `troca` recebe como argumentos o vetor de inteiros sobre o qual você quer operar.
- A função `opera` avalia a necessidade de fazer a troca em cada elemento do vetor e, se necessário, o faz.

```c
void opera(int *x) {
  char *number;
  int len;
  int i;

  len = (int)log10((double)*x) + 1;

  number = (char*)calloc(len, sizeof(char));

  sprintf(number, "%d", *x);

  for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    if (number[i] == '3') {
      number[i] = '7';
    }
    else if (number[i] == '7') {
      number[i] = '3';
    }
  }

  *x = atoi(number);

  free(number);
  return;
}

void troca(int *ar, int size) {
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    opera(&ar[i]);
  }
}
```

A função `opera`, cerne do problema, atua da seguinte maneira:

- Em `len` armazena-se a quantidade de casas decimais do número em questão (quantidade de dígitos presentes), calculada a partir do logaritmo em base 10;
- sabendo quantos caracteres há naquele número, requisitamos memória suficiente para armazená-los, com `calloc`, e fazemos com que `number` aponte para o início da memória reservada;
- em seguida convertemos o número inteiro para uma string utilizando `sprintf` e armazenamos o resultado em `number`;
- o laço itera sobre o número, dígito a dígito, verificando se ele é `3` ou `7`;
- caso um `3` ou `7` seja identificado, ele é substituído;
- após todos os dígitos serem verificados, o número modificado é convertido para um inteiro com `atoi`;
- finalmente, a memória requisitada com `calloc` é liberada com `free` (*MUITO IMPORTANTE*).

Foram utilizadas duas bibliotecas para a implementação da função `opera`:

- para as funções [`calloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/calloc/) e [`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/);
- para a função [`log10`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/log10/).

Para compilar um código compilado com a biblioteca `math.h`, você deve passar para o linker a flag `-lm`.